# KeyPressEvent doesn't work with Qscintilla Library (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qscintilla

EDIT : THE CODE IS THE RIGHT CODE, FOR MORE EXPLANATION LOOK IN COMMENTS ;)

I'm trying to do an auto completer for parenthesis with Qt and Qscintilla library but i don't know why, my program wont goes into keyPressEvent function.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <Qsci/qscilexerhtml.h>

#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    initializeUI();
    initializeEditor();

    editor->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::initializeUI()
{
    setWindowTitle("My Code Editor");
    setMenuBar(new QMenuBar(this));
    QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    fileMenu->addAction("&Open", this, SLOT(onOpen()), QKeySequence::Open);
    editor = new QsciScintilla(this);
    setCentralWidget(editor);
}

void MainWindow::onOpen()
{
    QString filename =  QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open .html file"),
                                                     QDir::currentPath(),
                                                    "HTML (*.html *.css *.php)");

    if (filename.isEmpty())
        return;

    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return;

    editor->setText(file.readAll());
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::initializeEditor()
{
    initializeFont();
    initializeMargin();
    initializeCaretLine();
    initializeLexer();

    initializeFolding();
}

void MainWindow::initializeFont()
{
    QFont font("Consolas", 12);
    font.setFixedPitch(true);
    editor->setFont(font);
}

void MainWindow::initializeMargin()
{
    QFontMetrics fontmetrics = QFontMetrics(editor->font());
    editor->setMarginsFont(editor->font());
    editor->setMarginWidth(0, fontmetrics.width(QString::number(editor->lines())) + 6);
    editor->setMarginLineNumbers(0, false);
    editor->setMarginsBackgroundColor(QColor("#cccccc"));

    connect(editor, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(onTextChanged()));
}

void MainWindow::onTextChanged()
{
    QFontMetrics fontmetrics = editor->fontMetrics();
    editor->setMarginWidth(0, fontmetrics.width(QString::number(editor->lines())) + 6);
}

void MainWindow::initializeLexer()
{
    QsciLexerHTML *lexer = new QsciLexerHTML();
    lexer->setDefaultFont(editor->font());
    //lexer->setFoldComments(true);
    editor->setLexer(lexer);
}

void MainWindow::initializeCaretLine()
{
    editor->setCaretLineVisible(true);
    editor->setCaretLineBackgroundColor(QColor("#ffe4e4"));
}

void MainWindow::initializeFolding()
{
    QsciScintilla::FoldStyle state = static_cast<QsciScintilla::FoldStyle>((!editor->folding()) * 5);

    if (!state)
        editor->foldAll(false);

    editor->setFolding(state);
}


bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);

    switch (keyEvent->key()) {
    case 40:
        editor->insert("()");
        break;
    case 60:
        editor->insert("<>");
        break;
    default:
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
    }

    return true;
}

return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
}
```

And there is my header file :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <Qsci/qsciscintilla.h>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QString>
#include <map>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();
   void initializeUI();
   void initializeEditor();
   void initializeLexer();
   void initializeFolding();
   void initializeMargin();
   void initializeCaretLine();
   void initializeFont();

protected:
   bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e);

public slots:
   void onTextChanged();
   void onOpen();

private:
   QsciScintilla *editor;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

When I use keyPressEvent function without Qscintilla Library that work fine but not here.

If someone can help me, that will be a pleasure :)

Comment: Are you getting a stack oveflow? I mean in `MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)` you should call `QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(e);` instead of `keyPressEvent(e);`

Comment: Thinking about this I expect the problem is `MainWindow` does not get the key press events. Your `editor` does.

Comment: @drescherjm so, with the `QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(e);` that doesn't work. And yes, i understand why my MainWindows doens't have keyPressEvent, but the Qscintilla key press event is protected and i don't know how use it, I just edit my code with `editor->keyPressEvent(e);`

Comment: My second comment is probably the reason.

Comment: I think you need an event filter instead of what you are trying to do. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html an example of this is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: @drescherjm mmm, okay I see what is event filter, I will try this and I tell you if that work ^^

Comment: @drescherjm so, that work, I get the event from Qscintilla class but now, nothing is writing in my editor haha have you any idea ? ^^

Comment: Did you add the else part like in the example code? I mean where it has the following comment: ***// standard event processing***

Comment: To be honest, i don't really know what I need to put here :/ I will edit my code to show you the entire.

Comment: You just call the base class in the else part so that the keys don't get filtered out. If you don't call the base all keys will be filtered out..

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you so much, that work now, I will edit my code to put the right code ;)