# Qt 5.7 implement my own class like widget for my project

Tags: c++, qt, qscintilla

I would like to create something like web editor, with a preview function. To do that, I created my editor with highlight function, ... and I use the WebEngigne class for my preview.

My problem is that i can't add my editor class in my project.
This is my editor code : [KeyPressEvent doesn't work with Qscintilla Library (Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706002/keypressevent-doesnt-work-with-qscintilla-library-qt)

And there is my IDE code :
mainwindows.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow:public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "texteditor.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWebEngineView *preview = new QWebEngineView();
    QWebEngineView *mixedPreview = new QWebEngineView();

    textEditor editor;

    preview->load(QUrl("https://google.com/"));
    mixedPreview->load(QUrl("https://google.com/"));

    this->ui->editorLayout->addWidget(&editor);
    this->ui->WebPreviewLayout->addWidget(preview);
    this->ui->WebMixedLayout->addWidget(mixedPreview);

    //QWebEngineView *mixed_browse=new QWebEngineView();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And my main class just call and show the mainwindow class.

I hope someone will help me, see you soon.
BEY

Comment: What do you mean "My problem is that i can't add my editor class in my project"?  You have made 2 projects and you want us to merge it? Is there some knowledge you miss in order to do it yourself?

Comment: yes, I have 2 projects, now I would like to merge it. But I don't know how add my class editor in my ui :/

Comment: General advise: first step is to Put the editor in it's own class with a small interface that can be called from mainwindow.  If done properly, this Editor class can be called from the mainwindow in this project.  I assume you know how to add header and source files to a qt-project.